# Remove all spaces and commas in a sentence

Tags: php, regex, drupal, drupal-7

I'm working with data migration using Drupal 7. I am migrating some taxonomy terms and I wanted to know how to remove spaces and commas from a sentence.

If this is the sentence:

' this, is my sentence'

The **desired** result that I'm looking for:

'thisismysentence'

So far I have managed to do this:

```
$terms = explode(",", $row->np_cancer_type);
    foreach ($terms as $key => $value) {
      $terms[$key] = trim($value);
    }
var_dump($terms);
```

which only gives me the following result:
'this is my sentence'
Anyone has a suggestion on how to achieve my **desired** result

Comment: I don't know php, but if you could split on `/[\s\pP]+/` then join the result array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use one `preg_replace` call to do this:

```
$str = ' this, is my sentence';
$str = preg_replace('/[ ,]+/', '', $str);
//=> thisismysentence
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
$row->np_cancer_type = str_replace( array(' ',','), '', $row->np_cancer_type);
```

Example:

```
$str = ' this, is my sentence';
$str = str_replace( array(' ',','), '', $str);
echo $str; // thisismysentence
```